# Правильно ли я понимаю причину возникновения ошибки доступа к памяти? (умные указатели)

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Есть вот такой пример из учебного пособия:
P.S. не обращайте внимания на auto_ptr, я знаю, что он признан устаревшим, и вместо него необходимо использовать unique_ptr и пр.

```
std::auto_ptr<SomeClass> a(new SomeClass);
// ...
SomeClass* ptr = a->get();
// ...
std::auto_ptr<SomeClass> b(ptr); // Ай!!!
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при выходе указателей a и b из области видимости сначала будет вызван деструктор указателя а, который удалит объект, а после деструктор указателя b, который захочет удалить уже удаленный объект и тем самым  вызовет ошибку доступа к памяти?
Знаю, что вопрос очень простой, но хочется удостовериться в том, что я понимаю всё правильно.
очень благодарю!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Понимаете неправильно, потому что деструкторы будут вызваны в порядке, обратном порядку объявления объектов - сначала `b`, потом `a`

Причина же ошибки вами понята верно - при выходе `b` из области видимости, будет удален объект `SomeClass`, так что `a` будет пытаться удалить уже несуществующий объект, что является UB.